# webbrowser.open() adding a / behind the input

Tags: python-3.x, python-webbrowser

I was trying out searching something using voice recognition, but the command was interpreted as an URL, where it will add a / after the command. The slash is making the word to be an URL. I don't want an URL, but just a normal word on the search bar.

eg:
me: "search animal"

results - animal/ (site cannot be reached)

**Is there a way to solve this?**

code as follows:

```
elif 'google' in command or 'search' in command:
        talk("Googling.")
        command = command.replace('google','') 
        command = command.replace('search','') 
        chrome_path = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe"
        webbrowser.register('edge', None , webbrowser.BackgroundBrowser(chrome_path))
        webbrowser.get('edge').open_new_tab(command)
```

Answer (score 0):

[webbrowser.open_new_tab()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/webbrowser.html#webbrowser.open_new_tab) expects a URL.

Add the search engine where you want to find the data for the query (command).

```py
webbrowser.get('edge').open_new_tab('https://google.com/search?q={}'.format(command))
```

The webbrowser module launches your browser and opens the specified web page in it.